# Beamer frame number without total

Tags: beamer, page-numbering

The command

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}
```

issues the frame number in the format a/b where a is current and b total. Is there a command that produces just a, in the same color, character, position etc? I'd prefer to avoid having to edit things at tex level or producing a new command.

Comment: Try on preamble `\setbeamertemplate
 {footline}{\quad\hfill\insertframenumber\strut\quad}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73418164/enumerating-slides-in-beamer-without-losing-the-footline

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The original definition from `beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty` is

```
\defbeamertemplate{footline}{frame number}
{
  \hfill%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
  \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
  \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber\kern1em\vskip2pt%
}
```

So if you want to keep colour, character position etc., try with

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{% 
  \hfill% 
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}% 
  \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}% 
  \insertframenumber%
  %\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber
  \kern1em\vskip2pt% 
}
```

But I'm not sure if this fulfils you not "tex level or producing a new command" requirements, whatever this means.

---

With an up-to-date version of beamer, this can be simplified to

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \hfill%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
  \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
  \setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[framenumber]%
  \usebeamertemplate*{page number in head/foot}\kern1em\vskip2pt%
}
```

Comment: That's good, thank you. I perhaps should also increase the \vskip value since now there is no / symbol, but I guess this is personal taste.

Comment: @jj_p The `\vskip` controls the vertical placement, this should not have changed. If you want to compensate the missing / you want a horizontal space.

Comment: Actually, I'm bothered not by the horizontal spacing, but the vertical, since \vskip space is counted from the / symbol, which is taller than the numbers, so this is why I considered changing it :)

Comment: This solution also removes the colored boxes from beamer styles that have them (like e.g. `\usetheme{AnnArbor}`).

Comment: @divenex Try `\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[framenumber]` or ask a new question

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz `\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[framenumber]` by itself works. Thank you!