# White box behind page numbers in beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer, boxes, pdfpages

I lost the codes for a beamer that I previously prepared. Now I am creating a new presentation with **exactly the same style**, and I am using the `pdfpages` package the include some pages of the pdf. However, the page numbers overlap with the previous one.

I would like to cover the page numbers of the included pdf so that the page numbers of the new presentation is clearly visible. A white box behind page numbers and above the included pdf would work really well.

Here is a sample code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]{}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
%old pdf have different page numbers so I want to hide them
\includepdf[pages={-}, pagecommand={}]{old.pdf} 
}

\begin{frame}
Some new stuff.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try with `pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}}`.

Comment: @Werner thanks for the quick response. However, I would like to show the pdf numbers of the new pdf, not the old one (and they are totally different). This is why I want a white box above the bottom right corner of the old pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333684/194703) here is how you can hack the framenumber.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{% 
  \hfill% 
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}% 
  \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}% 
  \fcolorbox{red}{red}{\insertframenumber%
  \,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}%
  \kern1em\vskip2pt% 
}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
%old pdf have different page numbers so I want to hide them
%\includepdf[pages={-}, pagecommand={}]{example-image-duck.pdf} 
}

\begin{frame}
Some new stuff.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You will need something like

```
 \fcolorbox{white}{white}{...
```

instead, i.e. white color instead of red, and you may need make the box a bit wider depending on the number of digits in the page numbers of the original slides, e.g.

```
  \fcolorbox{white}{white}{\phantom{1}\insertframenumber%
  \,/\,\inserttotalframenumber\phantom{1}}%
  \kern1em\vskip2pt%
```

For the future, I'd kindly like to ask you to include files like `old.pdf` that others do not have. If the file is essential, explain how you generate it, if not, replace it by some generic file.